# Can I host a Minecraft server from an iPad/iPod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

My iPad is, by far, faster than my laptop. Would I be able to instead host a Minecraft server on my iPad?

EDIT: I found that the iPad 2 (which I have) only has 512MB of RAM. However, I wanted to do this since whenever I get on my own server, I gets lag messages in the console. I figured that if I run it on an iPad, I could go onto my server while running various programs (Chrome, recording software, etc.) with little lag, at least compared to hosting it on my laptop which has 2GB RAM that runs MANY various programs that may or may not be crucial to my computer.

Comment: Why the down vote? Seems like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: Are you comparing the actual specs or just the apparent performance of the devices? Mobile devices can seem much faster on much "worse" hardware simply because they're running optimized tasks one at a time. If your laptop is really significantly slower than 1 Ghz, well, I just feel sorry for you.

Comment: @Wipqozn - I agree. Jonny B's question seems perfectly Goode to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Under normal conditions, you simply can't. You can't use the Desktop version of Minecraft on iPad because you can't run the Java files on iPad. A non-jailbroken iPad will never allow Java to run like that.

Some people are trying to get this to work with jailbroken iPads which can run java. [It's still not working](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/735803-run-a-server-on-a-ipod-touch-or-iphone/page__view__findpost__p__11756200), and only an iPad 3 would yield remotely acceptable performance for a low-end server. I strongly recommend against trying unless you're doing this as a "because I can" project.

If you mean for Minecraft Pocket Edition, you can just play locally with other MPE players over Wifi. It's really easy, but it's not a "Minecraft Server" in the same sense and Desktop players won't be able to access your "server".

Answer (score 2):

So far, a minecraft server has been utilized on an iPad 3, sporting the 1GB of RAM. The server boots up but the moment it gets to the portforward step, it fails. So far, nobody has been able to port forward on an iOS device. This progress was achieved on a jailbroken iPad 3, running the iFile, JavaVM, and Mobileterminal plugins available via Cydia.

On an ASUS Transformer android tablet however, a low level, vanilla minecraft server has been hosted and confirmed to work. Ports are forwarded, and local computers on the ASUS Transformer's internet connection can connect. The device is able to host the server in creative mode, with no mobs, and connect 2 people.

But to answer your question, Apple has made it so that this cannot be done. Well, not until we find out how to forward ports on a iOS device, such as the iPad 3.

Answer (score -7):

No you cannot, but you can play multiplayer with other Apple devices. 
Minecraft on iPod is not made by the people who made Minecraft for the PC.

Comment: Minecraft for iOS was made by Mojang, who also made the PC version, as you can tell by their logo which is displayed on both versions on launch. Maybe not the same _people_, but when Minecraft for iOS was developed, the developers **definitely** had access to the source code for the full version.

Comment: Um actually it is there game still but they hired another company to port it to all the mobile platforms and the 360.